# Is it possible to get a correctly typed sub-tuple?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript4.0

With [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) Typescript allows me to define generic Types that isolate Parts from a tuple type.
For the sake of simplicity in this question, let us just talk about splitting the first `length-1` elements and the last:

```
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [ ...infer Head, any ] ? Head : any[];
```

Now assume I have some typed tuple instance and want to get both

- the first `length - 1` elements and
- the last element

---

```
const args: [...T, D] // assume I have that in a context where T and D exist
const last: D = args[-1] // this works just fine
const head: T = args.slice(0, -1) // this does not - I have to cast as unknown as T
```

Is there a way to get the `head` properly typed without having to cast?

Comment: `args[-1]` shouldn't work and doesn't work. And no I don't think there is a way yet.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now you're doing `args[-1]` which doesn't work in JS or TS, and you haven't really defined/declared/initialized `args` or its type.  The answer to the question is  "not with standard TS libraries", although you could possibly merge a very complicated call signature to `slice()` to get behavior like that; are you interested in such a solution?

Comment: ... like [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/mLyPkW)?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it.  Let me know (and if you reply, please mention me via @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Answer (score 0):

You could declare some helper functions for your problem:

```
type Tuple = ["a", "b"]

function accessTypesafeIndex<T extends any[], K extends keyof T>(arr: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return arr[key]
}
const t: Tuple = ["a", "b"]

const x = accessTypesafeIndex(t, 1) // "b"
const z = accessTypesafeIndex(t, 0) // "a"
const y = accessTypesafeIndex(t, 2) // undefined

function last<T extends any[]>(arr: T): T extends [...any[], infer Rest] ? Rest : undefined {
    return arr[arr.length - 1]
}
const l = last(t)//"b"
function head<T extends any[]>(arr: T): T extends [infer Head, ...any[]] ? Head : undefined {
    return arr[arr.length - 1]
}
const h = head(t)//"a"
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=8&ts=4.7.4&ssl=19&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#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-nkVIVKpctAKpXiyW4IA)